# Azure AD Connect - How to sync group memberships?

Tags: azure, active-directory

We've started using Azure AD Connect to sync our user accounts for use with Office 365. The only problem is that only a tiny subset of our on-premises AD group is being uploaded to Azure AD. The 'odd' groups in our AD that are placed the same OU/folder as the users have synced. However the bulk of our groups that are in a separate OU/folder haven't synced despite being selected in the local "Azure Active Directory Connect" wizard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that nested groups aren't supported which might be the source of your issue - see section "Sync filtering based on groups" [on the Azure AD documentation site](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-aadconnect-get-started-custom/#pages-under-the-section-sync) for more information.